# Evaluate $T\colon\mathcal{P}_2\to\mathbf{R}^3$ at a particular polynomial in $\mathcal{P}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V = \mathcal{P}_2$, $W = \mathbf{R}^3$. I choose bases $\mathcal{B} = \langle t^2, t^2 + t, t^2 + t + 1 \rangle$ for $V$ and $\mathcal{D} = \Bigg\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\\ 3 \end{pmatrix} \Bigg\rangle$ for $W$. If I tell you that a linear transformation $T \colon V \to W$ has the matrix representation
>   \begin{equation}
> \operatorname{Rep}_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{D}}(T) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1\\ 3 & 0 & -2\\ 0 & -1 & 4 \end{pmatrix},
> \end{equation}
>   compute $T(3t^2 + 4t - 2)$.

I have the correct answer to this problem in front of me, but I have no idea how to get to it. Could someone show me the way to get to the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some hints:**

Write out $3t^2+4t-2$ in the basis $\mathcal B$.

> Its coordinates wrt $\mathcal B$ are $(-1,6,-2)$.

What would happen if you multiplied the coordinate matrix of the above by the matrix $\operatorname{Rep}_{\mathcal B,\mathcal D}(T)$?

> $\operatorname{Rep}_{\mathcal B,\mathcal D}(T)\pmatrix{-1 \\ 6 \\ -2}$ would be the coordinates of the image of $3t^2+4t-2$ under $T$ wrt $\mathcal D$.

If you knew the coordinates of $T(3t^2+4t-2)$ wrt $\mathcal D$, could you find the coordinates wrt the standard basis?

> Sure.  Just multiply each coordinate by the corresponding element of $\mathcal D$ and add.

Comment: Awesome! I got it, it was the second step in there that I couldnt figure out. Thanks